# Xcode 7: Binding an array controller to a radio button group

Tags: macos, cocoa, radio-button, xcode7, cocoa-bindings

I have a small set of objects from which the user should be able to select one using a radio button group. The objects are already bound to an array controller. Is there a way to bind that array controller to a radio button group so that additional radio buttons are generated dynamically? If possible, an IB solution is preferred.

Example project: https://scriptreactor.com/collectionviewtest_radio.zip

Goal is to be able to select one of the items "a", "b", "c", and have that selection available in the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the button state through `objectValue` (`NSTableViewCell`) in a view-based table, and `representedObject` in a collection view (`NSCollectionViewItem`).

If an `NSArrayController` is configured to generate cells/items for those parent views, the views will maintain the state of the `objectValue` and `representedObject` binding targets for each view in the collection.

So in IB, you have one generic subview with a radio button in it, and you should be able to select "Collection View Item" with a keypath of `representedObject.<whateverKeyPath>` for the binding of the radio button if it's within a collection view item.   Or you could select "Table View Cell" with a keypath of `objectValue.<whateverKeyPath>` if the button is a subview of a table view cell for a view-based table.

Though it may be dated by recent OSX 10.10 updates to `NSCollectionView`, the [quick start guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html) has good illustrations on how to configure bindings within subviews of collection views.   Table view subview bindings are similar, though you use `objectValue` rather than `representedObject` as the property within the view.

Comment: I've built a group with a NSCollectionView, and passed the different radio labels through an ArrayController and your representedObject approach. Now, I have the problem that I still need to bind the actual value (otherwise, selecting the radio buttons doesn't do anything). Additionally, the radio buttons don't behave as a group - i can select all of them at once.

Comment: You can bind the radio button to `selected` rather than `representedObject.<something>` and disallow multiple selection.    I thought perhaps you were targeting a binding to something in the model that already had a property, and allowing multiple selection.  I'm also not sure you need to radio button above and beyond the default selection behavior, but I suppose you can disable that to make it appear as you want.  FWIW, the old standard way was the deprecated `NSMatrix.`  It is annoying that they have not spelled out exactly how to replace that behavior.

Comment: I've tried with the NSCollectionView but can't seem to get the binding of the selection done. In the end, I would like to have a single selected object in my ViewController. Example project: https://scriptreactor.com/collectionviewtest_radio.zip

Comment: @Etan, if you got it working, telling others how to do without `NSMatrix` would be a great answer of your own here.

Comment: Haven't got it working so far. I've returned to using a popup button although they require two clicks from the user...