# Xcode 7 memory leak

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

Either I'm doing something terribly wrong or I discovered a serious memory leak on Xcode 7.
I'm trying to make a simple OS X app that uses bindings to update a Table View from an array of objects.
I create this simple model:

```
class Episode: NSObject {
    var path: NSURL
    var series: String
    var season: Int
    var number: Int
    var name: String

    init(path:NSURL, series:String, season:Int, number:Int, name:String) {
        self.path = path
        self.series = series
        self.season = season
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Then, in the ViewController I specify an array of Episodes and add two items in the viewDidLoad method

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var selectedEpisodes = [Episode]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        selectedEpisodes.append(Episode(path: NSURL(string: "file:///")!, series: "Foo", season: 1, number: 1, name: "Foobar"))
        selectedEpisodes.append(Episode(path: NSURL(string: "file:///")!, series: "fOO", season: 10, number: 99, name: "fOObAR"))
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

I then add a Table View to the Storyboard with 5 columns, 1 for each property of the Episode class. I add an NSArrayController to the View Controller Scene with this configuration:

[image: Array Controller Config][image: Array Controller Config]

I then select the NSTextField of each NSTableCellView and and add this binding configuration to it:

[image: NSTextField Binding]

When I start to build the project it builds just fine until it reaches the compilation of the storyboard where it hangs. A process starts called **ibtoold** which quickly starts using a lot of memory.

[ibtoold process leaks](https://vid.me/QS75)

Even if I stop the compilation from Xcode this process doesn't stop. If I don't manually force quit it, it quickly takes all the available memory until the whole system crashes. The OS pauses other apps etc, in order to try and save you but at this point you can only force restart the computer.

I'm I doing something completely wrong or is this a bug? If I'm doing something wrong, what is it, and if not, how can I fix this simple app?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: That last binding doesn't work the way you want.  You need to bind through the `objectValue` of the table cell.   With the AC bound to the tableView, the tableView will maintain the `objectValue` for you to bind to in each cell.

Comment: [This recent answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450823/xcode-7-binding-an-array-controller-to-a-radio-button-group/33454921#33454921) explains how to do the sort of binding I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Add the deinit on your class and look if the deinitialized message appear on console.

```
    class Episode: NSObject {
        var path: NSURL
        var series: String
        var season: Int
        var number: Int
        var name: String

        init(path:NSURL, series:String, season:Int, number:Int, name:String) {
            self.path = path
            self.series = series
            self.season = season
            self.number = number
            self.name = name
        }
        deinit {
            print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
        }
    }
```

Comment: It never finishes building so it doesn't run. I don't think anything gets initialized in the first place...