# Converting a cell-based NSTableView to a view-based NSTableView (bindings, Core-Data)

Tags: swift, core-data, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, popupmenu

I'm trying to convert a cell-based `NSTableView` to a view based one.
The table takes data from different Core-Data Entities through bindings.
The problem arises from one column that had a pop-up button cell in it.

With the cell-based tableView I bound the `NSTableColumn` content to the Entity's (in this case, `Account`) arrangedObjects (through an `NSArrayController`) and its `contentValues` to the arrayController (`arrangedObjects.accountName`).

I understand that the way to do bindings with a pop-up in a view-based table (according to [this sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/blishen/TableViewPopup) is to set the ***tableView*** content to the Entity's arrangedObjects (again the `Account` `NSArrayController`) and its pop-up button in the column's Table Cell View to a delegate object, but I can't get that to work. Besides, I need different Entities for three other columns.
I've posted a sample project [here](https://github.com/BillySangster/TableTest), if anyone would like to have a go and help me out. It's pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Are you also converting to storyboards? I think you have two seperate questions: how do I bind a pop-up in a view-based table view and how do I bind `NSArrayController`'s `managedObjectContext` in a storyboard.

Comment: Aye, I've gone from xibs to a Storyboard. I know how to bind an `NSArrayController`'s `managedObjectContext`, I've got that working for the other tables and columns.  It's binding the content to this pop-up that's the problem.

Comment: With view-based tables, you generally bind to the cell view's `objectValue`.  I talk about that somewhat [here(link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450823/xcode-7-binding-an-array-controller-to-a-radio-button-group/33454921#33454921).  The AC `content` binding to the table will ensure each cell's `objectValue` is the right entity.  So in each cell's view, just bind to `objectValue`

Comment: If the value you want in the cell is an attribute of the `NSArrayController` that the table is bound to, that works, aye. My problem is that the column is a different entity and therefore, attribute, to the one bound to the table. It's funny, because it's not just throwing an exception or crashing the app, it's freezing the whole laptop. It heats up after and soon becomes unusable and I need to restart it!

Comment: I had a look at your project but when I bind the popup, the storyboard compiler gets stuck in a loop, eats all my memory and Xcode hangs. It looks like a bug in Xcode or ibtool.

Comment: Exactly. Think I'll  file a bug. It's maybe not the correct way to use a pop-up button with a table (I've tried everything), but I don't thing Xcode should hang like that. I had to restart my Macbook as it continued after force quitting Xcode.Thanks for having a go! Good to see it's not just me. :)

Comment: Bug submitted to Apple.